# Get time from a varchar(100) type with (HH:MM AM/PM) format

Tags: php, mysql, time, fetch, typeconverter

How to convert the string ("RD/OT 07:30") to time. I just know how to convert ("07:30 AM") to time. This code below is giving me a blank data.

```
 $id = strtoupper($_POST['id']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT STR_TO_DATE('RD/OT 07:30','%x %h:%i')  as ScheduleIn  FROM tbl_uploadedschedule") or die(mysql_error());
    $res =   mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $r = $res['ScheduleIn'];
    return($r);
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a temporary table column and converting the varchar dates to date/timestamp records thus removing the problem all together?

Comment: @John - "7:30 AM", "RD/OT 7:30" - this is the data format coming from an uploaded .csv file/ excel file. Can this be converted to date/timestamp format just like what you've suggested?

Comment: what syntax error do you get?

Comment: If only there was a manual for this stuff

Comment: This is the error : "check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(100), loginTime(),108),1,5) as Time FROM tbl_cmsloginout WHERE campaign='$id' && agentName='ADARAYAN, DIANNE"

Comment: with this edited code, no error appear but only blank data.

Comment: Sorry for the disturb Sirs, I now get the exact info i need. I just need to use the MID() to retrieve only the 7:30 in the string "RD/OT 7:30" then use the STR_TO_DATE() to convert to time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE(str,format)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert time format:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`field_name`, '%h:%i %p')
FROM `table_name`
# this will convert '7:30 AM' to '07:30:00'
```

If whole DATETIME format is outputed, you can use [`TIME(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function to get only TIME part.

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97949/5/0)** (*don't know why sqlfiddle is ignoring TIME() function; it works on localhost*).

Comment: I tried this code but this only give me a blank data. Thanks.

Comment: "$id = strtoupper($_POST['id']);
   $upload ="";
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT TIME(STR_TO_DATE('loginTime', '%h:%i %p')) as Time FROM tbl_cmsloginout WHERE campaign='$id' && agentName='ADARAYAN, DIANNE'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @AlgieRosario: You cannot use field name as string, remove single quotation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, now i get the STR_TO_DATE(), the code:

```
STR_TO_DATE('loginTime', '%h:%i %p')  as Cast
```

is wrong because it reads the 'loginTime' as string which is an illegal time format. And the right syntax is:

```
 STR_TO_DATE(loginTime, '%h:%i %p')  as Cast
```

without the single quotation in the column name. Horray !